# MySQL fails to start: innodb-default-row-format=dynamic

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Restarted computer this AM - WAMPSERVER fails to start MySQL 8.0.26.

Log file contains the following:

```
2021-12-16T11:11:56.631237Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server]
c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.26\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.26)
starting as process 4896 

2021-12-16T11:11:56.645789Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.26\bin\mysqld.exe:
Error while setting value 'dynanmic' to 'innodb-default-row-format'.

2021-12-16T11:11:56.646988Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010746] [Server] Parsing
options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed. 

2021-12-16T11:11:56.647364Z 0
[ERROR] [MY-010168] [Server] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
```

If I comment out the line "innodb-default-row-format=dynamic" then MySQL will start but I don't understand the ramifications of having that line commented out.

I have not found anything related to this specific issue in my searches.

Any insight / solution greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could it be a simple spelling issue? The error message says `'dynanmic'` , whereas it should be spelled as `'dynamic'`

Comment: Btw, dynamic is this setting's default value, so you can remove this line from the config file altogether without any hassle. Which you could have found out had you checked the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just mispelled the word **dynanmic** on your configuration settings.
The default row format for InnoDB tables is already **DYNAMIC** (starting from v5.7, in the previous version it was **COMPACT**)

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's. They are almost never any use to others and that afterall is the main purpose of SO. We just make a comment like the one made by @Shadow and then close the question